# Inporting arbitrary Javascript functions into a Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm building a project in Vue.js, but it has a quite a lot of Javascript processing (it's all local, so I don't need to have anything server side), and I was wondering if there is a way to import a file that is basically just some processing (mathematical, structure processing, etc.) functions in Javascript - no template, etc. - into a Vue component? It's all working fine using methods in the component, but getting a bit large and "monolithic".

Comment: You can user spread operators within methods block, or [mixins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep working with several files and then just to the following.

```
import AlgebraicFunctions from 'algebraic-file';
import GeometricFunctions from 'geometric-file';
```

Using the spread operator:

```
methods: { 
 ...AlgebraicFunctions,
 ...GeometricFunctions
}
```

Comment: Do you have a simple working example of this - I can't seem to get it to work. TIA...